# Launch a few instances of Zygote process

Tags: android, dalvik

I would like to have a few Zygote processes in Android running in parallel.
Is it supported with the current sources?

If not what can I do to support it?

Comment: Android SDK apps are forked from the zygote. SDK applications can run in parallel on multi-core devices.

Comment: I would like to do a change to the ROM itself to be able to launch a few DVM in parallel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There would be little value in doing this on the current system.

All app processes are forked from the zygote process.  Once forked, they are independent processes each running their own copy of the Dalvik virtual machine.  The act of forking a new process is fast enough that you wouldn't gain anything by doing it in parallel.

You would reduce or lose many of the advantages of zygote, notably the sharing of a large chunk of the native and managed heap (via the Linux copy-on-write page handling).

The only value in having multiple zygotes would be if you needed different app processes to have radically different properties.

If you wanted to do this, you'd need to launch the different zygotes from initd and then provide a way for system_server to contact them.

Comment: I wonder how they did this:http://pdos.csail.mit.edu/~taesoo/pubs/2014/morula/morula.pdf where I can find the source code ?

Comment: Interesting paper; it seems my assertion of "little value" failed to take into account ASLR-related security concerns.  However, from the abstract: "Our evaluation shows that, compared to Zygote, Morula incurs a 13 MB memory increase for each running application".

Comment: Do you have a clue how they do that ? when I launch app_process with no argument it fails, how they spawn a pool of Zygote process?

Comment: They're not spawning a pool of *zygote* processes; they're defining a new sort of process with randomized addresses and pre-launching them to reduce app startup latency.  Android did something similar before zygote was introduced.

Comment: But it is written:The core idea of Morula is to adaptively maintain a pool of
Zygote processes with distinct memory layouts", can you point me to a way of doing that ? or what Android did before Zygote? I would like to do ASLR for it, for the purpose of learning the OS internals.

Comment: For this level of work, your best bet is to download the AOSP sources and do a case-insensitive search for "zygote", then dig through the code that comes up.  You'll need to understand the zygote process launch from initd (a/k/a app_process), the zygote fork code in Dalvik, and the zygote launch and specialization code in frameworks/base.  Probably start with Dalvik.